# The model backing the 'UserContext' context has changed when the first time build

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

when users create an account in my website, they will have a url like this domain.com/{username} and then it will show all the post of the user out. The blog will show a litle bit user's infomations. This is my model:

```
    [Table("Post")]
    public class Post
    {
        private DateTime _date = DateTime.Now;

        [Key]
        public int postID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string slugPost { get; set; }

        [AllowHtml]
        [Required]
        public string content { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime publicdate
        {
            get { return _date; }
            set { _date = value; }
        }
    }
```

This is my router:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Profile",
               url: "blog/{username}/",
               defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "index", username = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

This is my controller:

```
 private SystemContext db = new SystemContext();
 private UsersContext udb = new UsersContext();

 public ActionResult Index(string username)
 {
     var model = new ProfileContent();

     model.Profile = (from u in udb.UserProfiles
                where u.UserName == username
                select u).FirstOrDefault();

     model.Baidangs = (from p in db.Posts
               where p.username == username
                select p).ToList();
            return View(model);
 }
```

I always get the error

> The model backing the 'UserContext' context has changed

although that was the first time I build it, even I had removed it.

I got error "Invalid object name 'dbo.Posts'."

how can I solved those problems?

Comment: did you added a migration and executed the Update-Database command from the package manager? if NOT, this could be the reason.

Comment: You have two contexts. Did you add migrations for both?